# How to add list of lists as a column to existing data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe "df" which looks like this:

```
   Name
0. School
1. Organisation 
2. Teacher 
3. Guest
```

now I have three lists

```
1. from=['12','18',['11','10'],['12','4','8']]
2. to = [['11','9'],'','8','3']
3. status = ['yes','no',['yes','no'],'']
```

I want to add these 3 lists to my existing dataframe df and it should look like this

```
  Name          From   To   Status
0. School        12    11   Yes
0. School               9
1. Organisation  18         No
2. Teacher       11     8   Yes
2. Teacher       10         No
3. Guest         12     3
3. Guest          4
3. Guest          8
```

I have tried `df['from']=from` and `df['to']=to` 
But this didn't give me table as I expected.

Comment: Don't use `from` as a variable name, it's part of the [python import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first,we should flatten the list with a index,then use the `concat` method of `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["School","Organisation","Teacher","Guest"]})
From = ['12','18',['11','10'],['12','4','8']]
def flat(nums):
    res = []
    index = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if isinstance(nums[i], list):
            res.extend(nums[i])
            index.extend([i]*len(nums[i]))
        else:
            res.append(nums[i])
            index.append(i)
    return res,index
x="From"
list_flat,list_index=flat(eval(x))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({x:list_flat},index=list_index)
df = pd.concat([df['Name'],dataframe],axis=1,sort=False)
```

the result is:

```
           Name From
0        School   12
1  Organisation   18
2       Teacher   11
2       Teacher   10
3         Guest   12
3         Guest    4
3         Guest    8
```

Comment: x="From"
list_flat,list_index=flat(eval(x))
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({x:list_flat},index=list_index)
df = pd.concat([df['Name'],dataframe],axis=1,sort=False).                                       I used this for all 3 lists but only the last list got appended. I'm new to python. Correct me if i'm doing wrong

Comment: sorry,I'm trying to concat other columns,but the code would rise error.The reason maybe that the `concat`method should make sure that the index of dataframe is unique.
You can find more help in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html